# How to stop presenting share extension in "Open-In" options Menu View?

Tags: ios8, ios8-share-extension

I am developing share extension for my app. In my share extension info.plist , i added NSExtensionActivationSupportsImageWithMaxCount activation rule.So i expected my app share extension will present in any image share from any apps.But my issue is my app share extension also presenting in apple's Open-In options menu view.Is there any way to stop presenting my app in Open-In menu?

Note: My app has supports Custom URI schemes for different type documents.

Comment: Have you got any solution for this?

Comment: @karan have you got solution for this?